# How to show two or more markers on a Google map with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I have written this code to show map and mark with javascript code in the asp.net web page:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
   <script>
       var myCenter;
       var center;
       var isButtonClick = false;
       function initialize(x, y) {
           var mapProp = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),

               zoom: 5,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           myCenter: center;
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
           var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
               animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
           });
           marker.setMap(map);

       }
       google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () { if (!isButtonClick) initialize(0, 0) });
    </script>
```

and write this code in the asp button click event to send value to java script function:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "beh", "isButtonClick=true;initialize(35.878987,46.279637);", true);
```

every thing works! But I want to send two or more position or value to javascript function, for example send this value:

> 45.123321,35.123345
>   35.123321,45.123321
>   45.123456,34.123454

and mark all point on the map. How can I do this?Notice:Up value must send with asp button event to function,i have down code:

```
String[,] myArr = new String[4, 1];
            myArr[0, 0] = "45.123321";
            myArr[1, 0] = "35.454345";
            myArr[2, 0] = "20.123321";
```

how can i send up array to function?

Comment: check the answer, I updated accordingly

Answer (score 1):

```
function initialize(markersData) {
           var mapProp = {
               center: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),

               zoom: 5,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           };
           myCenter: center;
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
          for(var i=0;i<markersData.length;i++){
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               position: new google.maps.LatLng(markersData[i,0], markersData[i,1]),
               animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
           });
           marker.setMap(map);
          }
       }


initialize(markersData);
```

in C# decalre you array like this

```
// ... Create 2D array of strings.
float[,] markersData= new flaot[,]
{
   {45.123321,35.123345},
   {35.123321,45.123321},
   {45.123456,41.123454}
};

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "beh", "isButtonClick=true;initialize(markersData);", true);
```

Comment: Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "beh", "isButtonClick=true;initialize([
{'lat':45.123321,'lng':35.123345},
{'lat':35.123321,'lng':45.123321},
{'lat':45.123456,'lng':34.123454}]);", true);

Comment: I changed my answer accordingly :)

Comment: my c# code is this:String[,] myArr = new String[4, 1];
            myArr[0, 0] = "45.123321";
            myArr[1, 0] = "35.454345";
            myArr[2, 0] = "20.123321";

Comment: how can i send up value with:
   flag
 
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript?

Comment: you need to send array from your C# (which I don't know)
In javascript I have used array of objects

Comment: your array should be 2d array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77404/discussion-between-sunil-b-n-and-elnaz-irani).